# Which approach for getting the client url from the request to the API

Tags: rest, kubernetes, server

I'm going to deploy an app
Frontend (react) and .net (API) on kubernetes.

I'm thinking about best approach for getting the frontend URL from request hitting API.

Like for example send later an email to someone with link to the frontend. But before that frontend is sending a request to fire this email.

Solutions in my head :

1. Embedd frontend URL in environment variable
2. Take the frontend URL from Httpcontext (host, schema)
3. Use request header for that.